# Desfase en slider con Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css3

Estoy codificando un pequeño `slider` bastante simple y me encuentro con un problema que la verdad no se que es.

El `slider` funciona bien hasta que trata de volver a la primera foto, se ve el cambio de posiciones mostrando el mal funcionamiento y luego vuelve a pasar correctamente, el desfase es entre la última y la primera foto.

**En css tengo esto:**

```
.cambiaFoto {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.8s;
    position: absolute;
}
.cambiaFotoActivo {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.8s;
    position: relative;
}
```

**Código HTML:**

```
   <div class="col-sm-5 alinear-der" ng-controller="cambiaFoto">
     <img src="img/productos/foto1.png" alt="" class="responsive-img cambiaFoto cambiaFotoActivo">
     <img src="img/productos/foto2.png" alt="" class="responsive-img cambiaFoto">
     <img src="img/productos/foto3.png" alt="" class="responsive-img cambiaFoto">
   </div>
```

**Código Javascript:**

```
function cambiaFotoCtrl($scope){

    function miniSlider(){
        var activo = document.getElementsByClassName('cambiaFotoActivo');
    activo = activo[0]
    siguiente = activo.nextElementSibling
    if (siguiente == null){
        siguiente = activo.parentNode.firstElementChild
    }
    activo.classList.remove('cambiaFotoActivo')
    siguiente.classList.add('cambiaFotoActivo')
    }

    setInterval(miniSlider, 5000)

}
```

Ejemplo en [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/paw30e8b/)

Alguien tiene alguna idea de porque habría el desfase?

Comment: Hay alguna razón que no puedas utilizar alguna librería para realizar el slide? Recomiendo Swiper http://idangero.us/swiper/#.VyPQszCLQdU

Answer (score 1):

cambia "relative" por "absolute" en tu css

```
.cambiaFotoActivo{
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.8s;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Es muy inteligente, el problema es que tengo un div que contiene dos divs con height auto, uno con una imagen a la izquierda y el otro con texto a la derecha. Si le pongo absolute, no ocupa lugar en el dom y se superpone con el texto ya que el div padre no tiene altura fija.

Answer (score 1):

Ya resolví el problema, no era la solución que buscaba ya que lo que quería era hacer *fade-out* y luego *fade-in* con `opacity` y `transition`. El mini slider funciona bastante bien en cada slide, el problema es entre el ultimo y el primero. ¿Por que?, nosé.

Igualmente lo resolví de una forma que no quería :P. Le saque la linea de transition en la clase `.cambiaFoto`. De esta manera no hace *fade-out*, sinó desaparece completamente y luego hace *fade-in*.

Comment: Te recomiendo que coloques el código que finalmente vas a usar, para que así, ayudes a otros en un futuro.